# What is faster in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you have these elements:

```
<div id="articles">
    <article id="post-100" class="something"></article>
    <article id="post-200" class="something"></article>
    <article id="post-300" class="something"></article>
    <article id="post-400" class="something"></article>
</div>
```

Which would be technically better in terms of speed to find the elements and then manipulate them?

```
var articles = $('#articles');

    articles.find('.something.').addClass('another-class');

    // or

    articles.find('[id^=po]').addClass('another-class');

    // or

    articles.children().addClass('another-class');
```

I have a rather large number of elements of "article" type and I need to select them all, and was wondering which would be best to use?

Comment: How about you benchmark it?

Comment: You can test both scenarios here: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: you can try $('#articles .something.').addClass('another-class');  .It may be the fastest.

Comment: `document.getElementById('articles').children` is fastest, but who cares ?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/finds-vs-children/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to test it with jsperf: http://jsperf.com/finds-vs-children

For instance on Firefox 28 `children()` is the fastest.

Comment: That's great, I got the same results in Chrome, really handy tool!

Comment: My results show the same: http://jsperf.com/selectors-test31212132 I've added more "article" tags to be sure.